# How to include Swift libraries installed with Cocoa Pods when submitting iOS app to App Store

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have installed a few libraries that are necessary to run an iOS app that I made. I am ready to submit the app, however when I use Apple's "Application Loader" to submit my application, I am unable to submit the .workspace file associated with the Cocoa Pods - only the .xcodeproject file. how do I go about submitting the Cocoa Pods version?
Screenshot of issue:https://i.stack.imgur.com/TbAfe.jpg
Thank you for the help

Comment: Please post your error screen shot  while you  submitting .xcworkspace build.

Comment: @technerd As you can see it the .xcworkspace is not a selectable build

Comment: @technerd Forgot to add link. It is added now

Comment: Thats really not how you deliver an app.

Answer (score 0):

- Inside xcode, select the correct target (your main project, your app), change from simulator to "Build only device"
- From the menu, Product->Archive
- In the window that pops up (Organizer), click the large blue button "Upload to App Store" and follow the instructions.

Keep in mind you need to have the release provisioning profiles set on your target before trying to build.

Comment: What is "releasing provisioning profiles set on the target"? Thanks

Comment: In your Target->Build Settings->Code Signing-> Code Signing Identity. Select iOS Distribution (under automatic) for Release (you might need to expand code signing identity). And the under Provisioning Profile check that you are allowed to select a provisioning profile which matches your identity.